# Время выполнения отрезка кода

Tags: c++builder, c++

Есть код. Как узнать его время выполнения в м.секундах или ещё меньше? Не могу нигде найти( Помогите, пожалуйста. Код короткий, обычные функции с получением времени или простые таймеры не реагируют.

```
(начало отсчета времени)
// код
(Конец отсчета времени)
```

Спасибо за внимание!

Comment: Интересно, Вам важно время исполнения именно для работы программы, или для себя? Как вариант, рассматривается то, что, например, Code::Block (и ему подобные IDE) выводит время работы программы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый ответ самый простой для выполнения, его можно еще упростить
clock() находиться в библиотеке "time.h"

```
int t=clock();

код
{
}

cout<<clock()-t<<endl;
```

Comment: Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER t1, t2, f;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t1);
    //program
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&t2);
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&f);
    double sec = double(t2.QuadPart - t1.QuadPart) / f.QuadPart;
    cout << "\ntime " << sec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать несколько вариантов:

1. Стандартные c-таймеры, но для оч. быстрого кода придется сделать его (т.е. код) циклическим, чтобы время работы можно было измерить, а затем разделить на количество циклов.
2. Использовать точные OS-специфик таймеры, например, `QueryPerformanceFrequency`.
3. Использовать стороннюю библиотеку. Как пример могу привести библиотеку `FFTW`, в которой есть функции для вычисления коротких промежутков времени (тиков).

Я бы выбрал первый вариант.

**UPD.**

Ну как-то так:

```
#include <time.h>
...
const size_t cycles_max = 10000;
clock_t t0 = clock();
for(size_t i=0; i < cycles_max; ++i)
{
//измеряемый код
}
clock_t t1 = clock();
//Среднее время выполнения одного цикла, в сек.
double time_seconds = (t1-t0)*CLOCKS_PER_SEC/cycles_max;
```

Comment: А как реализовать не подскажите? минимальный пример дайте пожалуйста. Спасибо

Comment: Плохо. Зацикливание сильно нагружает систему. Кроме того, можно бы было вообще написать while(true){ /\*Some Code**/ break;}, но, опять-таки, сильная нагрузка (хотя, если код просто огромный, то этим можно пренебречь, например, если в коде используется ожидание).

Comment: Я же говорю, код - пример. Более того, задача исследовательская, так что в код продукта подобные измерения не должны попасть.
Если бы измеряемый код был "огромный", то не возникло бы проблемы проскакивания его за пару десятков тактов CPU, и возможно было бы вообще обойтись без зацикливаний.
А нагружает зацикливание систему, или нет, зависит от конкретного случая.

Comment: Конкретный случай из жизни -- это работа с портами, открытие и т.п. Я зацикливал прогу, но она систему совсем не нагружала.

Answer (score 1):

Я для таких целей использовал [GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Это не миллисекунды, это тики процессора. На каждой отдельно взятой машине можно написать простенькую программку, которая будет замерять количество тиков в секунду.

Comment: А пример кода с данной функцией маленький можно пожалуйста?)

Comment: Вот только мсдн с вами не согласен:)
Return value
The return value is the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.
Функция возвращает кол-во миллисекунд от старта системы.

Answer (score 1):

Использовать GetTickCount следующим образом

```
DWORD t = GetTickCount();
// Ващ код
t = GetTickCount - t;
cout << t << "ms" << endl;
```

Но нужно помнить, что реальная точность - 10-50 мс (зависит от точности таймера).
Если нужно ещё точнее - тогда [Rdtsc](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rdtsc)

Comment: Но если нужно ещё точнее - тогда код заворачивается в функцию и вызывается пару миллионов раз. Потом общее время делится на пару миллионов и получает точнее.

Но в реальной жизни все равно может быть по другому. Маленький код может очень хорошо влезть в кеш и выполнятся значительно быстрее.

Comment: @KoVadim, пример. В начале каждой, скажем, сотни мс вызывается функция, скажем, 1000 раз. В 1-ю милисекунду ф-кция будет вызвана 1000 раз, в 100-ю -- 2000 раз, в 200 -- 3000 раз и т.д. Весь прикол в том, что на 99-й мс ф-кция будет вызвана столько же, сколько и на 50, и на 1-й, т.е. 1000 раз. Логика ясна?

Comment: честно - я вообще не понимаю Вашей логики. Абсолютно. И даже не понимаю, к чему она.

Answer (score 0):

Напиши метод, который возвращает текущие время, поставить его в начале программы, а в конце вызвать еще раз и это время отнять от начального - будет разница. Или использовать профайлер.

Comment: GetTime не выходит слишком коротки промежуток времени
не успевает даже сообразить 0 выкидывает и все.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов на крайний случай. Можно создать второй **низкоприоритетный** поток, и в нем зациклиться, например, выполнять

```
    int flag=1; ///////////////// это лучше сделать глобальной переменной
    register int i=0; // i пишем в регистре проца, для ускорения, но это сильно
                      //нагружает систему
    while(true){
    Sleep(1);
    i++;
    if(0==flag) break;}
```

этот вариант не самый лучший, но рабочий. Заодно, в функции закрытия потока изменить значение переменной flag на 0. Значение i будет ответом в миллисекундах. Код работы с потоками есть в гугле=)...