# Глобальный аналог GetKeyboardState - существует ли GetAsyncKeyboardState?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, клавиатура

Как узнать была ли нажата любая кнопка на клавиатуре, чтобы определить активность пользователя (что он не афк)?

Идеально подходит снимать отпечаток клавиатуры через `GetKeyboardState` и сравнивать с предыдущим отпечатком, но он ограничен рамками приложения. Есть ли аналог или асинхронный вариант функции для глобальной проверки нажатия клавиши?

У функции для одной кнопки `GetKeyState` есть глобальный вариант `GetAsyncKeyState`. У `GetKeyboardState` в стандартном виде такой альтернативы нет. Возможно, есть какая-то самописная функция?

Использование DLL ловушки для такого пустяка кажется расточительным и разбираться в целой DLL из-за этого не хочется + возможная борьба с антивирусом в этом случае.

Comment: Можно для каждой клавиши вызвать функцию `GetAsyncKeyState` (всего 256 раз). Только эта функция не панацея, поскольку если другое приложение вызовет её же в промежутке между вашими вызовами, вы не получите достоверной информации о нажатии клавиши.

Comment: Здесь может помешать реализация - планируется проверять активность в таймере, у которого интервал - 1 секунда. 256 раз каждую секунду могут либо не уложиться в неё, либо слишком перегрузят функционал по производительности, учитывая, что в этом же таймере выполняются другие функции..

Comment: О реализации `GetAsyncKeyState` * 256 была мысль. Но вот вопрос: одинаково ли выполнение `GetAsyncKeyState` * 256 по скорости с `GetKeyboardState`?

Comment: Так протестируйте, [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/471679/177722) в помощь.

Comment: @zed , спасибо за `QueryPerfomanceCounter`. Проверил через неё.
Длительность выполнения в секундах:
GetAsyncKeyState*256=`0,0000661240`
при GetKeyboardState=`0,0000021136`
Выходит, разница всё же есть, пусть и это даже не доли секунды.
Использовал код:
`//каждая отдельно
for i:=0 to 255 do a[i]:=GetAsyncKeyState(i);
//общий слепок
GetKeyboardState(State);`

Comment: Вопрос остаётся актуален. В крайнем случае можно использовать `GetAsyncKeyState` * 256, но эта операция в 30 раз медленнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetLastInputInfo Retrieves the time of the last input event.

А вот пример использования
http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread1237003.html

Минимальная версия Windows 2000 (на Win 98 не заработает).

Ну и англоязычное обсуждение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442246/how-to-get-the-last-windows-active-time-by-windows-api

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Попробовал, но `GetLastInputInfo` всегда возвращает `False` на 64-бит, на 32-бит не пробовал. Код: `LInput: TLastInputInfo;  GetLastInputInfo(Linput); //возвращает False Linput.dwTime; //возвращает 0, потому что функция не отработала`. Пробовал `CallNtPowerInformation` - она возвращает данные в основном по активности загрузки системы, а не по времени простоя, к сожалению. Но попробую ещё дальше изучить обе функции. Возможно, что-то не так использую.

Comment: У функции `CallNtPowerInformation` в возвращённом результате `t.TimeRemaining=4294967295`. Это точно не время простоя. Попробовал вызвать её же через полминуты, она вернула на 30 меньше. Похоже, это время до отключения. В настройках системы нет условия выключения системы, поэтому, возможно, число такое большое. Вероятно, его можно использовать для сравнения сколько секунд не было активности.

Comment: Разобрался, помогло. Спасибо. Разница в TimeRemaining определяет сколько секунд не проявлялась активность в системе. Правда обновляется результат в функции примерно раз в полминуты-минуту. Конечно, не аналог асинхронного слепка клавиатуры, но в чём-то это даже лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Тут про SetWindowsHookEx  с хуком  WH_KEYBOARD_LL кто-то слышал? Работает глобально. Без экспортов ловушек. Я когда-то такую либу на VB6 делал... Считай подмена драйвера клавиатуры

Comment: Это всё равно получается та же ловушка, просто без использования DLL. Возможно, она полезна для глобального чтения клавиатуры, но слишком громоздка для простой задачи проверки активности. Плюс к ловушкам не всегда по-доброму относятся антивирусы. А так работать как аналог глобального KeyboardState, думаю, вполне действенна.